# Open Active Link on a PDF Using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf

I need to use VBA to open a PDF located on a particular website and navigate to a particular page in the PDF using 1 of the links that are located on the first page of the PDF. Using the FollowHyperlink method in VBA in MS Access I am able to open the PDF.  I entered the name of the link as the subaddress in the FollowHyperlink method but it still only takes me to the opening page. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Should we understand that you need to access an existing link in pdf? Do you want to accomplish that using standard VBA? Does your project have a reference to `Adobe Acrobat ... library`?

Comment: https://community.adobe.com/t5/robohelp/hyperlink-to-a-bookmark-in-pdf-file/td-p/3398730?page=1

Comment: Also https://www.devhut.net/2013/12/04/vba-open-a-pdf-to-a-specific-page/

Comment: So, would you like to acces a specific page of the pdf document, or to really follow a link on its first page, pointing to another document/URL?

Comment: Thank you. The PDF is at a public website not maintained by me or my client. I cannot change it's structure. It is a pdf with multiple pages. The URL goes to the first page. The first page has 3 columns with each item a name followed by a page number. The name and page number together form some kind of link (link or named destination - I don't know which). With any particular search I don't know the page number I need but I do know the name that precedes the page number. I tried Tim's and June7's without success. FaneDuru - follow link on 1st page to another page in the same PDF

Comment: I do want to accomplish this with VBA in Access because the search needs to come from the app I have created for my client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research through several sources I found I could call Internet Explorer (the COM functionality exists in IE but unfortunately, from what I was able to find, not in Edge) and using SendKeys open the desired web page and navigate to the particular page in the PDF that had the desired information.

The following code was the solution that works for this particular situation:

```
Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal 
nCmdShow As Long) As Long

Const SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3
Const SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2
Const SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1
Const SW_HIDE = 0


Sub OpenPageToSelectedNameInfo()

    On Error GoTo Err_OPtSNI

    Dim strListLink As String
    Dim strSelectedName As String
    Dim objIE As New InternetExplorer

    strSelectedName = "Selected Name"
    strListLink = "https://www.publicsite.com/directory.pdf"

    With objIE
        .Navigate strListLink
        .Visible = True
        .Silent = False
    End With

    ShowWindow objIE.hwnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL

    WaitSeconds 4           '     Wait for PDF to load before summoning 
                            '     Find panel

    SendKeys "^f", True     '   Open Find panel on PDF
    SendKeys "^-", True     '   Reduce screen size one step
    SendKeys "^-", True     '   Reduce screen size one more step

    SendKeys strSelectedName, True

    SendKeys "{TAB}", True  '   Tab to Find panel settings
    SendKeys "w", True      '   Select Whole Words Only
    SendKeys "{TAB}", True  '   Tab out of settings

    WaitSeconds 2           '   Wait for whole words only to take affect

    SendKeys "^G", True     '   Find next entry - moves from directory page 
                            '   to page with data matching selected name


    Exit_OPtSNI:
        Exit Sub

    Err_OPtSNI:
        strErrMsg = "Error coming from Open Page to Selected Name Info. _
                    Err # " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description

        MsgBox strErrMsg
        Resume Exit_OPtSNI

End Sub
```

The WaitSeconds call is to a separate procedure based on the Sleep API as follows:

```
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Milliseconds As Long)

Sub WaitSeconds(intSeconds As Integer)

    On Error GoTo Err_WS

    Dim strErrMsg As String
    Dim dteRelease As Date

    dteRelease = DateAdd("s", intSeconds, Now)

    Do
        Sleep 100
        DoEvents
    Loop Until Now >= dteRelease

    Exit_WS:
        Exit Sub

    Err_WS:
        strErrMsg = "Error coming from Wait Seconds. Err # " 
                   & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description

        MsgBox strErrMsg
        Resume Exit_WS

End Sub
```